# Error on installing pyqt5(pip install pyqt5)

Tags: python, pip, pyqt, pyqt5

I have installed pyqt5 once on another pc.

I am trying to install pyqt5 on my notebook.

My notebook specs are:
**64bit AMD Ryzen 7 5800H
MS Windows 10 Pro**

I tried :
`> pip install pyqt5`
on cmd
and had error:

```
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [140 lines of output]
      Collecting sip<7,>=6.4
        Using cached sip-6.6.1.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting PyQt-builder<2,>=1.9
        Using cached PyQt_builder-1.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 MB)
      Collecting ply
        Using cached ply-3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
      Collecting toml
        Using cached toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
      Collecting packaging
        Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-62.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2
        Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: sip
        Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [105 lines of output]
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\abstract_builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\abstract_project.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\api.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\argument_parser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\bindings.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\bindings_configuration.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\buildable.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\configurable.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\distutils_builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\exceptions.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\installable.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\project.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\pyproject.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\py_versions.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\setuptools_builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        copying sipbuild\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\distinfo
        copying sipbuild\distinfo\distinfo.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\distinfo
        copying sipbuild\distinfo\main.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\distinfo
        copying sipbuild\distinfo\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\distinfo
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator
        copying sipbuild\generator\python_slots.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator
        copying sipbuild\generator\specification.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator
        copying sipbuild\generator\templates.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator
        copying sipbuild\generator\utils.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator
        copying sipbuild\generator\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module
        copying sipbuild\module\abi_version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module
        copying sipbuild\module\main.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module
        copying sipbuild\module\module.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module
        copying sipbuild\module\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\tools
        copying sipbuild\tools\build.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\tools
        copying sipbuild\tools\install.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\tools
        copying sipbuild\tools\sdist.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\tools
        copying sipbuild\tools\wheel.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\tools
        copying sipbuild\tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\tools
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        copying sipbuild\generator\parser\annotations.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        copying sipbuild\generator\parser\instantiations.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        copying sipbuild\generator\parser\parser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        copying sipbuild\generator\parser\parser_manager.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        copying sipbuild\generator\parser\parsetab.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        copying sipbuild\generator\parser\python_exceptions.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        copying sipbuild\generator\parser\rules.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        copying sipbuild\generator\parser\tokens.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        copying sipbuild\generator\parser\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\generator\parser
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\apiversions.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\array.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\array.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\bool.cpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\descriptors.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\int_convertors.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE-GPL2 -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE-GPL3 -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\MANIFEST.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\objmap.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\pyproject.toml -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\qtlib.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\README.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\setup.cfg.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\setup.py.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.h.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.pyi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.rst.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sipint.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\siplib.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\threads.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        copying sipbuild\module\source\12\voidptr.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\12
        creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\array.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\array.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\bool.cpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\descriptors.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\int_convertors.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE-GPL2 -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE-GPL3 -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\MANIFEST.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\objmap.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\pyproject.toml -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\README.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\setup.cfg.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\setup.py.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.h.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.pyi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.rst.in -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sipint.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\siplib.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\threads.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        copying sipbuild\module\source\13\voidptr.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64_clang-cpython-39\sipbuild\module\source\13
        running build_ext
        building 'sipbuild.code_generator' extension
        error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for sip
      Failed to build sip
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I searched for this error and tried several solutions:

```
> pip install --user --upgrade pip
> pip install pyqt5
```

```
> pip3 install pyqt5
```

```
> python3 -m pip install PyQt5
```

```
> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
> python -m pip install pyqt5
```

Also, I read the article that my python version is 3.10 or higher may cause problems, so I tried reinstalling the python version to 3.9.

The above solution doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: Try to upgrade pip, *not* in user mode: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, then `python -m pip install pyqt5`. Unless you also have Python 2, in that case you must use `python3` (and the correct pip command is `pip3`).

Comment: the command ```> python -m pip install --upgrade pip``` shows ```Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\msys64\clang64\lib\python3.9\site-packages (22.1.1)```  I still get an same error with that command... I have edited my post.

Comment: try `pip install pyqt5-sip`

Comment: error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')

Comment: same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72243791/sip-installation-fails-plat-name-not-recognized-correctly

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this problem lately, one fix for me "Python 3.7" was installing pyqt5 sip first, and pyqt5 after.

perhaps it is useful for others.

```
pip install "PyQt5-sip==12.7.0"
pip install "PyQt5==5.13.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by installing the latest Python version 3.10.5, updating pip alone did not help. I was using Python 3.8.9 before that.

Answer (score 0):

You may have python installed somewhere else on your computer that isn't the latest version and your system environment variables is pointing to that. Make sure there isn't a Python installation in another program or library. For example, I had a python installation in MSYS2 and once I uninstalled it from my computer it installed.

Answer (score 0):

For me installing version 5.12.2 of PyQt5 solved the issues.

```
pip install PyQt5==5.12.2
Pip install PyQtWebEngine==5.12
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, tried everything available on slack and other sources but found same error again again, people suggested to update the python version, sometimes python version is the constraints to run any application. this needs to be solved. then only we can proceed with other installation.

I have tried conda instead of pip or pip3 (pip and pip3 was not able to solve the problem, even after upgrade), and this works on my system.

```
conda install PyQt5
```